# Run code after login/Principle is assigned in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication

Ok, So i'm new to asp.net authentication and authorisation, this is my first day looking at it so I'm probably going about things the wrong way and I'm really hopeful someone can point me in the correct direction.

I need to run some code after the user has "logged in", whether that is by Forms auhentication, windows authentication or even custom authentication.

I need this code to run just once after each login, so am I correct to rule out handling Application_AuthenticateRequest/Gobal_asax_PostAuthenticateRequest?  These appear to form part of the pipeline for every request.

After looking at how asp.net handles the whole authentication and authorisation process: http://man.ddvip.com/web/bsaspnetapp/LiB0321.html ,I'm struggling to find a hook. I started looking into the code and found that the FormsAuthenticationModule fires a couple of WebBaseEvent but, hooking into asp.net helath monitoring feels like a hack and I haven't found the WindowsAuthenticationModule firing the same ones. The windowsAuthenticationModule doesn't appear to raise anything and I can't see anything being raised from HTTPContext.SetPrincipalNoDemand (Httpcontext doesn't apear to raise any events).

Is there some neat way to do this or should I look into some kind of work around?

Should I take another look into the HttpApplication class? It seems to be pretty agnostic to when an authentication module has resolved the user.

I haven't yet looked into whether I can hook into the setting of the Auth cookie, is this an avenue worth pursuing?

Comment: Are you creating a general purpose framework or something? Because when you say "forms, windows or even custom", it sounds like you could have no control over the way users are authenticated.

Comment: Our software is installed at the client and they get to determine how they want users to be authenticated so yes, we have no control over that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there is no something as "after user has logged in". From the server perspective, consecutive requests are not related. There is no easy way to determine whether or not current request is the "first one after authentication" or "second/third or yet another".

Without supporting few possible authentication schemes in an **explicit** way, you probably won't find any satisfiable solution. A possible approach would be to run your code in the `AuthorizeRequest` event of the general pipeline and issue a cookie to mark current session as "already handled". This could be problematic however if the browser doesn't support cookies (or the support is not reliable).